# gulp task can't find karma.conf.js

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

I am trying to run karma test via a gulp task. I use https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma and for some reason gulp cannot locate my karma.conf.js. That file is located in the same folder as the gulpfile. The root of the project. No matter what path I put, I get the same error File ./karma.conf.js does not exist.  I cannot figure out how to path it correctly.  Here is the code for the gulp task.

```
gulp.task('tdd', function (done) {
  new Server({
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
  }, done).start();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

This is how I spool up karma using Gulp ( and both files are in the same root ).

```
var karma = require('karma');

gulp.task('karma', function (done) {
  karma.server.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  }, done);
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you are running NODE.js then

[NODE Explnation for __dirname link](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

> "The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in."

If you are not running NODE.js, then perhaps all you needed was

```
configFile: '/karma.conf.js'
```

But if you are running NODE then use the first example.

Comment: Where is __dirname defined? It would seem to be undefined if i were to do it this way..

Comment: Well I am using gulp, which is a Node app. Just adding __dirname, worked like a champ. Node must make it available to gulp. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good point about Gulp being installed by NODE. Would you say this has answered your question?

Answer (score 3):

If another destination directory is assigned to `__dirname`, then it doesn't work.
Try this:

```
var Server = require('karma').Server
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
   new Server({
     configFile: require('path').resolve('karma.conf.js'),
     singleRun: true
   }, done).start();
 });
```