# gulp karma task - karma.config.js doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, gulp, karma-jasmine

```
     var karma = require('karma');

     gulp.task('test', function(cb) {
           var server = new karma.Server({
           configFile:require('path').resolve('karma.conf.js'),
           singleRun: true
      }, cb);
     server.start();
         });
```

The above is my gulp code and the karma.config.js is in the root(where gulpfile is present).

I get the error 'karma.config.js' doesn't exist!

Just can't fix the issue

I did try these - [gulp and karma, file karma.conf.js does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873279/gulp-and-karma-file-karma-conf-js-does-not-exist)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try printing the current directory using console.log(__dirname); That might help you solve the issue.

Comment: Thx silly me! its just merely a typo. karma spelt uppercase :(